# Stack address for Thread and the main process

Tags: process, pthreads

I have a question related to the memory address of thread and process. The question is:-
In normal call like

```
int func(int a, int b){
    int c;
    c = a + b;
    return c;
}         

int main(){
    int ret = func(a,b);
     return 0;
}
```

In the above function call to function func, the function variable a and b will get stored on stack. Please correct me, If I am wrong.

Now the other situation is when we are creating threads from the main process.

```
void * func(void *dummy_ptr){
    int c;
    c = a + b;
    pthread_exit();
}         

int main(){
    pthread_t  id;
    int ret = pthread_create(&id, NULL, & func(), NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

My question is where the variable of the pthread_create will get stored. Is it getting stored on Stack of main, or on the stack of thread.

Comment: Your examples won't compile, as you missed to declare `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 1):

`pthread_create` allocates space for the new thread's stack in the heap. So the variables inside of `func` are stored on the thread's stack, which itself is located in the program's heap.

Comment: Yes this is correct. For the function func() variable, which is called inside the pthread_create api, the variables will get stored on stack of the thread, but what about the the variables which we are passing in the API pthread_create(), like pthread_t id, Any thread attributes and the last argument pass like some integer or structure pointer.

Answer (score 0):

The variable `pthread_t id` is local to main so it must be created on the stack of main.

When `main` finishes execution and,

- You don't have a `pthread_join`  in `main` to wait until the thread terminates.
- The thread is not detached.

`main` exits causing all other threads to terminate abrubtly (kill).